# Represent Gender in Person Class

Tags: c#, class, enums

With a Person class, how do I go about representing Gender, I want to create it as a class, much like the `System.Drawing.Color` setup, but I am unsure how to do this.

So I can do `Gender = Gender.Male` or `Gender = Gender.Female` etc.

Sorry if this makes no sense.

Comment: Do some reading about [enums in C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032.aspx).

Comment: You are probably looking for enumerations..

Comment: Can i not create it as a class, and also a static class with the options, like Drawing.Color?

Comment: You might want to follow [ISO/IEC 5218](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_5218). The correct term is "sex", not "gender", although "political correctness" is trying to pervert the meanings. However, language does evolve.

Answer (score 8):

You could create an enum:

```
public enum Gender { Male, Female }
```

and then use it as below:

```
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public Gender Gender { get; set; }
}

var person = new Person
{
    FirstName = "Foo",
    LastName = "Bar",
    Gender = Gender.Male
};
```

Comment: That is not politically correct. How do you represent shemale? Or `Apache Helicopter`?

Comment: Where is the Gender enumeration created? In the Person class?

Comment: It's up to you. In the Person class is one option.

Comment: @bc004346 I mentioned the values Male and Female, since these values have been mentioned by the OP. Of course anyone can add as many values in this enum provided that these values make sense for her application.

Comment: @F17CH I would opt to create it in a separate file, called `Gender.cs`

Comment: I'm still confused as to where to create the enum, so that outside files can still reference it when creating the person.

Comment: @F17CH You should add a file called in `Gender.cs` to your project. Then you should add the definition of the enum there, `public enum Gender { Male, Female }`. Marking the enum as public you state that every type in your assembly or in any other assembly that references your assembly would have the opportunity to access and use your enum. I hope that I answered your question. If not, please let me know. Thanks !